# IPHONE: For UITableViewCell - how do I break lines for the NSString to make it fit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsstring

I have the next problem. In one of the cells (UITableViewCell) I need to show quite a long string. I am trying to break it in lines (adding \n) between words, but it does not seem to help (to be precise -- the string has \n, but it still shows like "My long string very..." in the cell) How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`your_cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;`